# error 419 (unknown status) in laravel using swagger

Tags: laravel-5, swagger

All request methods in laravel returned **(error 419 unknown status)** except get request.
How can I set token in header?

I tried to do this the following ways.

**1)**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
     ...
     headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     }
  }); 
}
```

**2)**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
     authorizations: {
        csrf: function () {
            var cookiearray = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookiearray.length; ++i) {
               if (cookiearray[i].trim().match('^XSRF-TOKEN=')) {
                  this.headers['RequestVerificationToken'] =
                     cookiearray[i].replace(`XSRF-TOKEN=`, '').trim();
               }
            }
            return true;
        },
     }
  }
}
```

**3)**

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
   data: {
      "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
   },
});
```

**4)**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: {
     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
   }
});
```

***but nothing has changed***

Comment: These look like api calls are you sure you want to use csrf here and not use api endpoints?

Comment: Yes,I'm sure that I want to use csrf, 
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: thanks a lot for your question,I have already fixed this issue